# URLs in some web applications (short URLs)

Tags: url, alias, short-url

I have a question about short URLs. Let me ask by giving an example.

We have this URL : `www.domain.com/controller/function/parameter/?get=1`

How can we show this URL like this : `www.domain.com/ShortName`

For example in joomla cms we have `Alias` that allows us to shorten the URL even with UTF-8 characters.

How can it be possible in php?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to research URL rewriting.

Here is a very detailed article that provides a wealth of information and some examples:

http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php

Here is an example.

In your .htaccess file you would enter something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)-([a-z]+) http://corz.org/blog/index.php?archive=$1-$2 [NC]
```

This translates an unfriendly URL like this:

http://corz.org/blog/index.php?archive=2003-nov

into a friendly and easy to remember URL like this:

http://corz.org/blog/2003-nov